# SQL - How to query for multiple WHERE values with AND operator

Tags: mysql

I'm a SQL newbie and have been searching for an answer to this but haven't found it yet. Say I want to query for all students that got a score of 80 from a table named students. How would I go about it? I have tried this so far, but it looks like the IN operator is similar to OR since it is giving me results of everyone that got an 80 on any of the tests.

```
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE test_name IN ('Quiz','Midterm','Final')
AND test_scores='80';
```

Thank you ahead of time for the assistance!

Sample data:

```
 Test Name |  Student ID   |  Student Name  |  Test Score
 Quiz      |   10          |    Tom         |  80
 Midterm   |   50          |    Sally       |  70
```

The results I would like to get back are all the columns of students who got 80 for all three tests. I apologize for the delay, but I guess I don't have the email notifications working properly. I did warn you I was new. I'm going to try the recommended steps to see how it goes. I'll report back.

Comment: Your query would return all students who got an 80 on _any_ of those 3 tests. What result do you want?  Please post a small sample of rows from your table, together with the output you would expect your query to return from that sample rowset.

Comment: Are you looking for students who got exactly 80 on _each_ of those 3 tests? That is a bit more complicated and requires some aggregation.

Comment: Showing some sample data and what you are hoping to get as results in this and future questions would help.  Use spaces for alignment as tabs don't work well on formatting. Just edit existing question with sample data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i'm going to try to include some sample data but formatting is an issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if the sample data you posted included students who match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to negate the sense of the test, and then exclude those students:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students
WHERE student_id NOT IN (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM students
    WHERE test_name IN ('Quiz','Midterm','Final')
    AND test_scores != '80';
)
AND test_name IN ('Quiz','Midterm','Final')
```

Comment: Although this did return the students that got 80's on all three tests, it also included additional students that got 80's on any of the tests. I'm going to continue at it tomorrow. Thanks again for getting me one step closer!

Comment: It will also return students who didn't take all 3 tests, but got 80's on the ones that they did take.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with a `having` clause, assuming that you want a score of 80 on all three tests:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM students
WHERE test_name IN ('Quiz','Midterm','Final')
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING SUM(test_score = 80 and test_name = 'Quiz') > 0 AND
       SUM(test_score = 80 and test_name = 'Midterm') > 0 AND
       SUM(test_score = 80 and test_name = 'Final') > 0;
```